# Error when converting base64 to image file in PHP

Tags: php, base64

I get an error when I convert base64 to an image file, it creates an image file but when I open it, it is an error image file?

[image]

In the image error message: **Looks like we don't support this file format**

My code is as follows

```
public function Base64ToImg($str,$ouput){

$bs64 = (strpos($str, ",")) ? explode(',',$str)[1] : $str;
$bin = base64_decode($bs64);
$size = getImageSizeFromString($bin);
$ext = substr($size['mime'], 6);
$ouput = $ouput.".$ext";
file_put_contents($ouput,$bin);
return $ouput;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The error is not in my code but because I am sending base64 code the image via POST method but in my base64 code contains `+` character so when sending via POST it will be removed `+` character goes error, I used js code `logo = logo.replaceAll("+","*");` to convert character `+` to `*` and PHP code `$logo = str_replace("*", "+", $logo);` to convert `*` back to `+`, and it worked fine for me

Comment: Can you share the base64?

Comment: Please, make your update as an answer and mark it as accepted/useful. It help others to identify the most useful answer at once.